# Ruby crashing and emitting 'Illegal instruction'

Tags: c, ruby, debian

On a client's legacy Rails 2.1.1 app, I'm encountering an error where ruby crashes and emits 'Illegal instruction.' The crash is triggered by calls to methods on Digest::SHA2.

```
>> Digest::SHA2
=> Digest::SHA2
>> Digest::SHA2.new()
Illegal instruction
```

The Rails app is running on two servers behind a load balancer. The stacks on the two servers are very close to being identical and only one triggers the crash. They're both REE 1.8.7, Rails 2.1 and Debian 6. One is running the Linux kernel version 3.9.3 and one is running version 3.9.2—but I'm unsure how to determine if that's even relevant.

`Digest::SHA2` seems to be mostly implemented in C. I know very little C and diagnosing this one is over my head. Any help / pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a bunch!!

**Environment Info**

Here's the REE source for `Digest::SHA2`:
https://github.com/FooBarWidget/rubyenterpriseedition187-330/tree/master/ext/digest/sha2

On the server that's encountering the crash:

```
hostname@node1:~/appname$ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 \n \l

hostname@node1:~/appname$ uname -a
Linux node1.hostname.org 3.9.2-x86_64-[redacted] #1 SMP Tue May 14 17:16:34 EDT 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux

hostname@node1:~/appname$ which ruby
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/ruby

hostname@node1:~/appname$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'digest'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Digest::SHA2.hexdigest('foo')
=> "2c26b46b68ffc68ff99b453c1d30413413422d706483bfa0f98a5e886266e7ae"
irb(main):003:0> exit

hostname@node1:~/appname$ ./script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.1.1)
>> Digest::SHA2.hexdigest('foo')
Illegal instruction
```

On the server that is *not* crashing:

```
hostname@node2:~/appname$ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 \n \l

hostname@node2:~/appname$ uname -a
Linux node2.hostname.org 3.9.3-x86_64-[redacted] #1 SMP Mon May 20 10:22:57 EDT 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux

hostname@node2:~/appname$ which ruby
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/ruby

hostname@node2:~/appname$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'digest'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Digest::SHA2.hexdigest('foo')
=> "2c26b46b68ffc68ff99b453c1d30413413422d706483bfa0f98a5e886266e7ae"
irb(main):003:0> exit

hostname@node2:~/appname$ ./script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.1.1)
>> Digest::SHA2.hexdigest('foo')
=> "2c26b46b68ffc68ff99b453c1d30413413422d706483bfa0f98a5e886266e7ae"
```

Comment: Is the Linux kernel version the only difference?

Comment: I'm not used to diagnosing this type of problem and am not sure what to look at in terms of differences. Do you have any advice?

Comment: Is the failing one the one with the earlier Linux kernel?

Comment: Yep, the failing one is running 3.9.2, the one that's not failing is running 3.9.3

Comment: Well, then, if it's not too much trouble, I would upgrade the kernel.  You already have a working machine with 3.9.3, so it's not like it hasn't been proven.

Comment: Thanks, that's not a bad idea.